# Updating a row based on a value from another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

So I have two tables "books" and "bookOrder" and they look something like this:

**`bookOrder`**

```
| orderID | book name   | required | availability
| --------|-------------| ---------| ------------|
| 1       |Harry Potter | 9        | yes         |
| 2       |Twilight     | 8        | yes         |
| 3       |Bible        | 8        | yes         |
```

**`books`**

```
|book name   |quantity|
|------------|--------|
|Harry Potter|10      |
|Twilight    |5       |
|Bible       |8       |
```

I want to be able to update the the "bookOrder" availability column based on the "books" table.

So far my SQL query is as follows:

```
UPDATE bookOrder
SET avalability = case when (
SELECT quantity
FROM books
WHERE books.bookName = bookOrder.bookName
) < (SELECT required From bookOrder WHERE bookOrder.bookName = books.bookName) THEN 'NO' END;
```

But I am getting an error:

> ```
> missing FROM-clause entry for table "books"
> ```

I might just have the query completely wrong.

(P.S. I know it's completely ridiculous that anyone would want to buy 8 Twilight books.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`UPDATE` syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) as [advised by Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70222505/939860), but add one more `WHERE` condition:

```sql
UPDATE bookOrder bo
SET    availability = CASE WHEN b.quantity < bo.required THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END
FROM   books b
WHERE  b.bookName = bo.bookName
AND    bo.availability IS DISTINCT FROM CASE WHEN b.quantity < bo.required THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END;
```

This way, Postgres only writes a new row version where the value actually changes. This can have a major impact on write performance - and general database performance. See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

`availability` should really be data type [`boolean`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html), in which case you can simplify:

```sql
UPDATE bookOrder bo
SET    availability = (b.quantity >= bo.required)
FROM   books b
WHERE  b.bookName = bo.bookName
AND    bo.availability IS DISTINCT FROM (b.quantity >= bo.required);
```

If referential integrity is enforced with a FK constraint and all involved columns are defined `NOT NULL`, simplify some more:

```sql
...
AND    bo.availability <> (b.quantity >= bo.required);
```

***Or*** drop the column completely and look up `availability` dynamically. Such an attribute can be outdated on arrival. You could use a [`VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) for this:

```sql
CREATE VIEW book_order_plus AS
SELECT bo.*, (b.quantity >= bo.required) AS availability
FROM   bookOrder bo
LEFT   JOIN books b USING (bookName);
```

Oh, and use legal, lower-case, unquoted identifiers to keep your life with Postgres simple. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Answer (score 1):

I would use an update join here:

```sql
UPDATE bookOrder bo
SET availability = CASE WHEN b.quantity < bo.required THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END
FROM books b
WHERE b.bookName = bo.bookName
```