# Trigger keeps updating value in every row instead of particular one

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to calculate a sum for each particular order. I am using this trigger but it doesn't work properly, it updates every row with the same value instead of the only one with proper id.

done_services table

```
id
service_id
price
```

service table

```
id
name
```

payment table

```
id
sum
service_id
```

```
CREATE FUNCTION make_sum() RETURNS TRIGGER
    AS $$
        BEGIN
            UPDATE payment
                SET sum = (select sum(price) from done_services where service_id = new.service_id);
            RETURN NULL;
    END;$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    
CREATE TRIGGER make_sum
AFTER INSERT ON basket FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION make_sum();
```

I used this command to enter an item
`insert into done_services(id, service_id, price) values(uuid_generate_v4(), '76594d2f-7153-495f-9671-0ddaa331568c', 100);`

But the sum changed for both rows instead of the only one with service id
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFAsk.png)

Comment: `basket`? Please make your question consistent. And always declare your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just missing something in your UPDATE statement :

```
UPDATE payment
   SET sum = (select sum(price) from done_services where service_id = new.service_id)
 WHERE service_id = new.service_id ;
```

Next time please create a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14) with your data model, sample of data and queries.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate cause for the error message is the missing WHERE clause as instructed by Edouard. Plus, prevent expensive empty updates like:

```sql
UPDATE payment p
SET    sum = ds.sum_price
FROM  (
   SELECT sum(d.price) AS sum_price
   FROM   done_services d
   WHERE  d.service_id = NEW.service_id
   ) ds
WHERE  p.service_id = sum_price
AND    p.sum IS DISTINCT FROM ds.sum_price;
```

In addition to fixing the prime error, this prevents empty updates that would not change the sum, but still write a new row version at full cost.

But the whole idea is questionable.

Keeping a sum from  many rows up to date via trigger is expensive and error prone. Did you cover `DELETE` and `INSERT` accordingly? What about `TRUNCATE`? What about concurrent write access? Race conditions, deadlocks?

To get get the current sum for a set that can change dynamically, the superior solution is typically *not* to save that sum in the table at all. Use a `VIEW` or `MATERIALIZED VIEW` instead.
Or, to get the sum for a single or few payments, use a function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_payment_sum(_service_id int)
  RETURNS numeric
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT sum(d.price)
FROM   done_services d
WHERE  d.service_id = _service_id;
$func$
```

Related:

- [Updating a row based on a value from another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70222476/updating-a-row-based-on-a-value-from-another-table/70226295#70226295)